# (Oracle) One-to-one and Insert queries

Tags: mysql, database, oracle, relational-database

I'm trying to insert data into 2 tables.

```
CREATE TABLE tableA
(
    primaryKeyA INT PRIMARY KEY,
    foreignKeyB INT
);

CREATE TABLE tableB
(
    primaryKeyB INT PRIMARY KEY,
    foreignKeyA INT
)

ALTER TABLE tableA
CONSTRAINT fk_tableA 
    FOREIGN KEY (foreignKeyB) REFERENCES tableB (primaryKeyB);

ALTER TABLE tableB
CONSTRAINT fk_tableB 
    FOREIGN KEY (foreignKeyA) REFERENCES tableA (primaryKeyA);
```

How would I go about to `INSERT` data into one of these constructions? If I try it tells me it is missing a parent key, which is true, but I have no idea how to create without needing the same key during that creation.

Comment: Please post your insert statement.

Comment: INSERT INTO PRODUCTSOORT ("primaryKeyA", "foreignKeyB")VALUES(1,1);
This would give me the error telling the foreignKeyB is missing sinc I have not yet created it

Comment: You need these constraint for sure ? You have to remove from either table because it is like cyclic thing. A depends upon B and B depends upon a

Comment: I'm not sure. I'm using this in my database to add aditional data to a account so that I won't have 40 fields in 1 table. But I guess I can just go for a 40 field table.

Comment: Not sure how the structure of your table is but I have bunch of tables for my website. Product table has basic information, productteam has same you have two id product id and team id, third table has information about the team

Comment: Based on this circular argument, you can't.  Because the foreign key target columns are both nullable, you could insert into productsoort primarykeya) values 1) and then insert in the other and then do updates.  This entire structure, though, is a very complicated way to do something much more simple.  The information from your test tables is woefully insufficient to do more than we have.

Comment: Thinking about this, I would like to describe foreign keys a bit.  While what you have modeled is "strange", it is not impossible.  The reason is that foreign keys can be either mandatory (table a must have a key from table b and vice versa - which in this scenario is impossible) or table a must contain a key from table b IF a value is supplied for the column.  In other words, your foreign key columns are not currently not null, so you could insert both tables and then update them with the correct values.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you have here is a many to many relationship .. you should have a middle table to help resolve this.

For example: (sorry, syntax not tested, no access to a DB at the moment)

```
  CREATE TABLE tableA
  (
      primaryKeyA INT PRIMARY KEY
  );

  CREATE TABLE tableB
  (
      primaryKeyB INT PRIMARY KEY
  );

  CREATE TABLE tableAB
  (
      primaryKeyA INT ,
      primaryKeyB INT 
  );

  ALTER TABLE tableAB
     ADD CONSTRAINT pk_tableAB
        PRIMARY KEY (primaryKeyA, primaryKeyB);

  ALTER TABLE tableAB
  CONSTRAINT fk_tableAB_B
      FOREIGN KEY (primaryKeyB) REFERENCES tableB (primaryKeyB);

  ALTER TABLE tableAB
  CONSTRAINT fk_tableAB_A
      FOREIGN KEY (primaryKeyA) REFERENCES tableA  (primaryKeyA);
```

Basically, if you think of Table A as "Customers" and Table B as "Addresses"  (for a simple example), 
You have a situation where:

A customer can have many addresses (ie Residential, Mailing, etc.)
An address can belong to many customers (ie multiple people living in same house).

That's a Many to Many relationship, and as others mentioned, if you create the FKs for that, you end up with a "circle" and you can't insert anything.
So you need to "break" the link. You do that by using a middle table, to describe the relationship.

Hope this helps.

** Also, is it MySQL? or Oracle? .. it can't be both ;) Although my solution should work for both